# Facebook url scraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm trying to implement facebook like url scraper. The one in which you enter the website url and facebook fetches videos or images, title, description form that page. Facebook uses the og:meta tags for scraping a website. Does facebook lets us use their url scraper or url debugger. Is their any other way in which you can do that?

I tried using yahoo query language. But it does not return property attribute of meta tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this gem https://github.com/intridea/opengraph

It parses the page and extracts og info:

```
require 'opengraph'

movie = OpenGraph.fetch('http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1217700-kick_ass/')

movie.title # => 'Kick-Ass'
movie.movie? # => true
movie.image # => 'http://images.rottentomatoes.com/images/movie/custom/00/1217700.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with that gem is that it works only if page has og information.

Comment: If you want to scrape a normal page like FB does, you need to parse the entire DOM looking for the tags you need. AFAIK facebook looks for images, videos, and takes title and description. I don't know if there's some gem out there that simulate fb scraper behaviour but you can use a DOM parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), and easily implement your own logic.

Comment: Hey thanks. I end up doing the same. I was looking for some easier client side alternative. But its ok, I will do it using server side.

Comment: @SuperEngineer could you share some snippet to point me how it's done? Or, have you found any autoparser since then?

Comment: take a look at this. https://github.com/super-engineer/url_scraper. Might give you an idea how its done.